# dkms for ixgbe fails with *** No targets

Tags: linux, drivers, centos, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to setup DKMS for the Intel ixgbe driver.  Below are the steps that seemed most correct, however I am not successful with this or other variations.  I'm using CentOS 7.

I'm using the latest driver from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/ixgbe%20stable/5.3.5/

After download, my steps:

```
sudo tar xf ./ixgbe-5.3.5 -C /usr/src
```

I created a dkms.conf file based on the info from here: https://www.xkyle.com/building-linux-packages-for-kernel-drivers/

File: /usr/src/ixgbe-5.3.5/dkms.conf

```
MAKE="make -C src/ KERNELDIR=/lib/modules/${kernelver}/build"
CLEAN="make -C src/ clean"
PACKAGE_NAME="ixgbe-dkms"
PACKAGE_VERSION=5.3.5
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION=src/
BUILT_MODULE_NAME="ixgbe"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION="/updates"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

Then I add to dkms and try to build:

```
$ sudo dkms add ixgbe/5.3.5
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/source ->
                 /usr/src/ixgbe-5.3.5
DKMS: add completed.

$ sudo dkms build ixgbe/5.3.5
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j32 KERNELRELEASE=4.4.115-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 V=1 -C src/ KERNELDIR=/lib/modules/4.4.115-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64/build...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.115-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/build/make.log for more information.

$ cat /var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/build/make.log
DKMS make.log for ixgbe-5.3.5 for kernel 4.4.115-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 (x86_64)
Wed Feb 14 17:08:01 EST 2018
make: Entering directory `/var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/build/src'
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/build/src'

$ ls -l /var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/build/src/Makefile 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6035 Dec 18 19:09 /var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/build/src/Makefile
```

If I change directory to /var/lib/dkms/ixgbe/5.3.5/build/src and type "sudo make", the build process starts and succeeds.  What am I missing?  I also tried the instructions from http://xmodulo.com/build-kernel-module-dkms-linux.html, but that just gives different errors.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The problem being that I unzipped into the wrong folder (make sure you the files are in /usr/src/ixgbe-version.

See this guide: https://gist.github.com/kslimani/6c289105fd21033c87d3ae378e793b69#install-ixgbe-module-with-dkms-support